# Black frame instead of edge detection image in PySimpleGUI with openCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pysimplegui

I'm coding a Python program to automate image processing tasks (threshold images, detect borders, optical flow, etc.) using PySimpleGUI, openCV and Numpy. However, when I run all the code and press the button that takes me to the function to obtain the image with border detection through the graphical interface, only a black box appears, but implementing only the border detection function by itself seems to work without any problem. Here is the code of the border detection function:

```
def correl_Sobel(image_filename=None):
image = cv2.imread(image_filename)

img_gray = (image[:,:,0]/3+image[:,:,1]/3+image[:,:,2]/3)
img_th = img_gray

img_th[img_th < 120] = 0
img_th[img_th != 0] = 255

img_th = abs(img_th)

vertFilter =[[-1,-2,-1],[0,0,0],[1,2,1]]
horiFilter = [[-1,0,1],[-2,0,2],[-1,0,1]]

img_edges = np.zeros_like(image)

n, m = img_gray.shape

for x in range(3, n-2):
    for y in range(3, m-2):
        pixels = img_th[x-1:x+2, y-1:y+2]
        
        verticalPixels = vertFilter*pixels
        vertScore = (verticalPixels.sum()+4)/8
        
        horizontalPixels = horiFilter*pixels
        horiScore = (horizontalPixels.sum()+4)/8
        
        #formula
        edgeScore = (vertScore**2 + horiScore**2)**0.5
        #three-layered images
        img_edges[x,y] = [edgeScore]*3
#pixel values / maximum value
img_edges = img_edges/img_edges.max()
return img_edges
```

And here is the code for the GUI and button implementation:

```
prev_filename = correlated = thresholded = convolution = None

while True:
   #read window
   event, values = window.read()
   if event == '-EXIT-' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
       break
if event == '-FOLDER-':
    folder = values['-FOLDER-']
    img_types = (".png", ".jpg", "jpeg", ".tiff", ".bmp")
    try:
        flist0 = os.listdir(folder)
    except:
        continue

    fnames = [f for f in flist0 if os.path.isfile(
              os.path.join(folder, f)) and f.lower().endswith(img_types)]
    #update file directory
    window['-FILE LIST-'].update(fnames)
#Select a file
elif event == '-FILE LIST-':
    try:
        filename = os.path.join(values['-FOLDER-'], values['-FILE LIST-'][0])
        image = cv2.imread(filename)
        window['-IN-'].update(data=cv2.imencode('.png', image)[1].tobytes())
        window['-OUT-'].update(data='')
    except:
        continue

#edge detection button
elif event == '-CONV-':
    try:
        if values['-FILE LIST-']:
            filename = os.path.join(values['-FOLDER-'], values['-FILE LIST-'][0])
            correlated = correl_Sobel(filename)
            # plt.imshow(correlated)
            window['-IN-'].update(data=cv2.imencode('.png', image)[1].tobytes())
            window['-OUT-'].update(data=cv2.imencode('.png',correlated)[1].tobytes())
        else:
            continue
    except:
        continue
```

Here's what happens when I press the edge detection button: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rrMd.png)

And here's what it should look like (I got this image by running only the function above): [edgeDetectedImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSfuM.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `correl_Sobel` is in float and <= 1, you may need to convert it into `np.uint8` by `(img_edges*255).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: thanks, it worked!